# Odd result for intercept in ANCOVA

Tags: r, ancova

I try to perform an ANCOVA for data with two factors and one covariate. The first factor has 2 levels and the second has 4.

```
    Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
    (Intercept)   7.9342    3.1123   2.704   0.0311 *
    k[T.2]      -4.3127     1.8957  -1.248   0.2122  
    k[T.3]       -2.453     1.6786  -1.557   0.1432  
    hg[T.2]      2.2411     2.4353   0.891   0.3219  
    hg[T.3]      4.3456     2.2342   1.668   0.1263  
    hg[T.4]     -3.5233     2.2318  -0.682   0.5108
```

I seem to be getting 2 coefs for the first factor and 4 for the second.
I would like to note that they are of type "factor" so that R would not treat them as numeric.

Why is this happening and is it normal?

Comment: Can we see your code? It's hard to know if we don't know what you did. Can you run summary(data[varsinthemodel])?

Comment: Even the answer to this question contains a request for clarification so I think this question is pretty unclear.

Comment: What does "this" in the question refer to?  Everything looks fine to me: your model is supposed to have 2+4 parameters and, sure enough, your output provides 6 estimates.

Answer (score 1):

This output looks like it came from `summary(lm(...))`. It looks like R produced two dummy codes for `k` and three for `hg`. That would mean R thinks `k` has three levels, not two (three codes for four levels of `hg` is normal). Also, it appears you haven't included your covariate, unless that's what `k` is supposed to be.

If you want *F*-tests of your factors, not slope coefficients and *t*-tests for dummy variables, try the `aov` function instead, preferably after ensuring that R is handling your variables the way you want it to. [Here's an example of an ANCOVA problem with R code that you may find helpful](http://r-eco-evo.blogspot.com/2011/08/comparing-two-regression-slopes-by.html).

BTW, if you have a question about the intercept, please [edit it in](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/96658/edit), or reconsider this question's title. If you're wondering about the significant result, it refers to the difference between the intercept coefficient and the null hypothesis, which probably defaulted to zero.